# Query if any results equal when getting count

Tags: php, sql

I am currently querying the database to get a count:

```
$onorder = $db->selectRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM store_orders");
```

The results will be like:

```
$onorder['Count'];
```

How do I update the query to find out if ANY of the results counted have a value of `1` for a column named `Priority`?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY HAVING` clause maybe ? Can you update your question to include your DB structure and the output that you need ?

Comment: you should not use keywords as variables, tho

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM store_orders where Priority = 1` ???

Comment: @devpro clearly this is the answer, combined with a check if the number of rows is larger than 0, though I'm convinced OP want's to handle this binary check with SQL rather than doing the check in his php function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 $onorder = $db->selectRow(
     "SELECT COUNT(*) as a, COUNT(IF(Priority=1,1,NULL)) as b FROM store_orders");
```

and have:

```
$onorder['a'];
$onorder['b'];
```

Inside the `COUNT` you put a condition so it won't count everything:

```
IF([condition], [result if true], [result if false])
```

This way it only`COUNT()`s the ones with value `1` and not the `NULL`s.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be performing as I was hoping. Could you please explain the `Priority=1,1,NULL` part? What is this doing exactly?